# iframe does not show in IE8

Tags: html, css, iframe, ie8-compatibility-mode

I have a hotel reservation system inside an iframe that does not show specifically in IE8.  I'm thinking this is a DOCTYPE issue?

You can view it http://bit.ly/15NHLAv

This is the doctype for the website.  The iframe itself does not have a doctype declared.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9" <?php language_attributes(); ?>> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" <?php language_attributes(); ?>> <!--< [endif]-->
```

Comment: There's a script error, saying jQuery is undefined. Much probably that's not the real problem, but worth it a look. Anyway... I can't see any difference on the website loaded on Firefox, Google Chrome or IE 10/9/8.

Comment: maybe its an issue with res-main-container not displaying properly..not the iframe?

Answer (score 0):

I've found that it'll only show the `iframe` if the inner width of the browser (`document.documentElement.clientWidth`) is 1095px or larger. Any lower and it gets pushed underneath (this happens with other browsers I tested with, too). However, in IE8 the `iframe` is covered by another element (I couldn't find which), but I fixed it by adding the following CSS style:

```
.iframe-home-res {
    z-index:10000;
}
```

This forces the `iframe` to render on top of all the other elements (unless they have a `z-index` greater than 10,000, which you would have to manually set).

You might want to look at your `iframe`'s code separately though, looks like your `<select>` is in the wrong place.